# How can I add more results to a COUNT()

Tags: sql

I'm using the COUNT function to find the number of conversations on a unit. A message has the id of the recipient as `to_id` and id of the sender as `from_id`. I'm defining a conversation as all messages that are exclusive to two id's. So all messages that are exclusive to two users on one unit.

```
(select count(distinct to_id) 
 from messages 
 where unit_id = units.id AND units.creator_id = from_id) as messages
```

This part works. But the problem is that it doesn't also count conversations where the creator_id = to_id and the creator didn't send a message back.

So I was either going to make a separate query that counts all of those specific messages and then adds it to the count or try and figure out how to add this functionality to the original query. I don't know how to add with SQL or how to do both.

Here's the complete statement:

```
SELECT 
   messages.*, units.*, 
   MAX(messages.created_at) AS 'conversation_date', 
   (select count(distinct to_id) 
    from messages 
    where unit_id = units.id AND units.creator_id = from_id) as messages,
   WEEKOFYEAR(MAX(messages.created_at)) as 'woy', 
   YEAR(MAX(messages.created_at)) as 'year',
   classifications.description AS 'classification'
FROM 
   messages 
JOIN 
   units ON units.id = messages.unit_id
JOIN 
   classifications ON units.classification_id = classifications.id
WHERE 
   from_id <> units.creator_id 
GROUP BY 
   messages.unit_id, from_id, to_id
```

Comment: Little confused by your sql statement... unit_id = units.id -- I don't see a table aliased to units here, where is units.id coming from?  You can either expand the where clause to have an or clause, or a union that picks up the to_id counts and adds them (nesting a few subqueries there).

Comment: @Snubber . . . Perhaps you should edit your question and include the complete SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    (
    (select count(distinct to_id) from messages where unit_id = units.id AND units.creator_id = from_id)
    +
    (select count(distinct to_id) from messages where unit_id = units.id AND units.creator_id = to_id )
    )

 as messages
```

OR

```
(
select count(distinct to_id) from messages where unit_id = units.id AND units.creator_id IN (from_id,to_id)
)
 as messages
```

Is this what you are trying to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really follow, providing sample data and the expected result would make your intention easier to understand.

However, I `think` you just need an OR condition inside that correlated subquery. Like this:

```
SELECT
      messages.*                                        --<< note                     
    , units.*                                           --<< note   
    , MAX(messages.created_at) AS 'conversation_date'
    , (
            SELECT
                  COUNT(DISTINCT m.to_id)
            FROM messages as m                           --<< change
            WHERE units.id = m.unit_id                   --<< change
                  AND units.creator_id = m.from_id       --<< change
                  OR units.creator_id = m.to_id          --<< NEW
      )                                    
                                           AS messages
    , WEEKOFYEAR(MAX(messages.created_at)) AS 'woy'
    , YEAR(MAX(messages.created_at))       AS 'year'
    , classifications.description          AS 'classification'
FROM messages
      JOIN units
                  ON units.id = messages.unit_id
      JOIN classifications
                  ON units.classification_id = classifications.id
WHERE from_id <> units.creator_id
GROUP BY
      messages.unit_id
    , from_id
    , to_id
```

I changed it to use a table alias `m` also, it's easy to get lost in what table is being referenced without them.

note: I should mention that using `messages.*, units.*` isn't good practice, any non-aggregate fields you need in the select clause should be part of the group by clause.